# toLowerCase inside map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get an image (countryflag) returned right by my country name. The problem is that I get returned iso2 in capital letters and the API only accepts lowercase letters.

As of now the url in the code is returned like: https://disease.sh/assets/img/flags/LT.png and I need it to return https://disease.sh/assets/img/flags/lt.png (all lowercase letters) instead.

```
return (
        <ul>
          {data.map(d => (
            <li key={d.countryInfo._id}>
              <img src={"https://disease.sh/assets/img/flags/" + d.countryInfo.iso2.toLowerCase() + ".png"}></img>
              {d.country} has total {d.cases} different cases as of today.
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
```

I have been trying to use .toLowerCase() in the end of d.countryInfo.iso2 (since it's a String) but then I get `TypeError: d.countryInfo.iso2 is null`

Comment: Sounds like it's not actually a string, but `null`

Comment: it is returned as a String in capital letters if I do not use .toLowerCase() method.

Comment: I bet it's actually null for at least one of them.

Comment: How would you suggest reading it in lowercased letters then?

Comment: Some of them are returned as null, not capital letter strings. You can skip if it is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't render `img` if `d.countryInfo.iso2` is `null`:

```
<ul>
    {data.map(d => (
        <li key={d.countryInfo._id}>
            {d.countryInfo.iso2 !== null &&
                <img src={"https://disease.sh/assets/img/flags/" + d.countryInfo.iso2.toLowerCase() + ".png"} />
            }
            {d.country} has total {d.cases} different cases as of today.
        </li>
    ))}
</ul>
```

You could also display a default `img` when `d.countryInfo.iso2` is `null`: